# vb parse word from clipboard into html

Tags: vb.net, parsing, ms-word

I want to copy some word text with tables, links and images and paste it into a rich textbox in my vb project. Where I want to parse it to html.

The Questenion is, how can access the copied word in the clipboard. Using

```
My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()
```

just returns text, without the structure for links, tables or images. But there have to be a way to access it, because my rich textbox seems to know the word format. When I paste it into it, tables, images and links are also displayed in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to specify text format in `GetText's` parameter as follow :

```
Dim htmlText As String = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html)
```

Comment: thanks, didn't expact it's that easy. But it's a bit strange, that word gives class attributes to elements, without "".